# Песня "Вьюн над водой" — что такое вьюн?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Существует такая русская народная песня — "Вьюн над водой".

Вьюн над водой, ой, вьюн над водой,
Вьюн над водой расстилается.
Жених у ворот, ой, жених у ворот,
Жених у ворот дожидается.

Очень красивая. И пелась она бы и пелась, без задумываний. Если бы вдруг не пришлось ее однажды на английский переводить. Что, вдруг, за вьюн такой, что над водой? Не растение же нам привычное. А что тогда? В интернете еще нашлась версия, что это туман. Но нет доказательств. И в словарях ничего толкового не находится.

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости "вьюн" здесь *венок*. То же значение мы встречаем и в другой народной песне "Со вьюном я хожу", исполняя которую девицы надевали именно венок.

На Руси было популярно гадание на суженного с помощью венка, если венок плывет по воде спокойно (выстилается), то замужество будет в этом году, а если крутится, то придётся свадьбу подождать. Это вполне согласуется с текстом песни, которую вполне могли петь девицы, при подобном гадании.

Comment: Это, кажется, не гадание. "Вьюн над водой устилается, Жених у ворот увивается.Свадебная песня. Из центральной части России. Как и многие обрядовые песни, закреплена в цепочке действа. Этой песней встречают свадебный поезд жениха у дома невесты". http://www.playcast.ru/communities/obschaga/?act=news&id=42454

Comment: @Vera Так и логично было бы его встречать песней о том, что предшествует браку. Венки вообще тесно ассоциируются в народных верованиях с браком, а вот про туман и карпов я подобного не встречал.

Comment: Вот ещё одна версия слова <<ВЬЮН>> . ВЬЮН — (бел.) водоворот, кругообразное течение, происходящее от встречи двух противоположных течений или как следствие отражения струй воды от берега. Самойлов К. И. Морской словарь. М. Л.: Государственное Военно морское Издательство НКВМФ Союза ССР,… …
Морской словарь

Comment: @следопыт такой вьюн **на** или **в** воде, но не над водой.

Comment: @МаркИз . Согласен . Вообще , я поместил это значение , чтобы показать , что значений слова может быть несколько .

Answer (score 1):

Могу высказать предположение , что слово <<ВЬЮН>> в этой песне обозначает водное растение **кувшинка** , из семейства лилиевых . Иначе её называли речной нимфой . Кувшинки (их есть несколько видов) растут в самых разных водоёмах и **устилают** поверхность воды также , как и ординарный вьюнок вьётся по земле или зарослям . Вот я тут скопировал цитатку (по интернет/ссылке [нимфея , лотос , лилия , кувшинка](http://www.lepestok.kharkov.ua/story/s20090401.htm)) : "Научное название белой кувшинки – нимфея. С этим водным растением у многих народов мира связано много легенд и преданий. ......
Славяне считали белую лилию волшебным цветком, приписывая ему магические свойства – он помогал против козней нечистой силы, излечивал от всех болезней. Отправляясь в дальнюю дорогу, люди зашивали в маленькие мешочки – ладанки – листья и цветки белой кувшинки с верой в то, что лилия предотвратит несчастья в пути."                                                                            ==============================================================================[image: кувшинка - 1]                                                         [image: Кувшинка - 2]

Comment: А есть какие-либо свидетельства, что кувшинку называли вьюном?

Comment: @МаркИз . Пытался найти по словарям . Не нашёл . Но я же выразился тут очень осторожно : <<Могу высказать предположение , что ... >> . Тут чисто логическое умозаключение . Но , согласитесь , что кой-какое внешнее сходство речной кувшинки с ординарным наземным вьюнком присутствует .

Comment: @МаркИз . И она явно  <<у с т и л а е т с я>>  .

Answer (score 1):

**Еще одна версия:**

1) Вьюн на воде (2003) // «Народное творчество», 2003.08.18

Я узнала о бытовании в этих местах таких песен, как  «Вьюн на воде». Ее мы впервые услышали, будучи в этнографической экспедиции в Вохомском районе в 1982 г. Не все знают, что вьюн на воде ― **это водоворот, воронка на воде**.

2) Что такое "Вьюн"? 
Вьюн (бел.) — водоворот, кругообразное течение, происходящее от встречи двух противоположных течений или как следствие отражения струй воды от берега (Морской словарь).

3) Другой текст  [https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/Вьюн_на_воде/Кир_I.1_(ДО)](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8C%D1%8E%D0%BD_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80_I.1_(%D0%94%D0%9E))

Вьюнъ на водѣ извивается,
А зять у воротъ убивается:
„А теща моя, теща ласковая!
Отдай мой даръ, мою суженую!“ —
Вывезла теща сани лаковыя9):
„Это не даръ и не суженая10)!“

Answer (score 0):

**В качестве версии**

Вьюн над водой расстилается... Может быть, выстилается (вьется, быстро двигается), выражая беспокойство, тревогу.

1) **Вьюн - рыба из семейства карповых** , внешне напоминает угря или змею, держится в иловатых и тинистых водах.Есть у вьюна  одна интересная особенность: он чутко реагирует на изменение атмосферного давления. Перед ненастьем он начинает беспокоиться и поминутно высовываться на поверхность (10-15 раз за минуту). За это свойство вьюна называют живым барометром. К поверхности воды вьюн поднимается редко. Но наблюдательные рыбалки отмечают, что быстрое плавание его на мелководье с поднятием придонного ила предшествует длительному ненастью.http://www.dreamfisher.ru/opisanie-ryb/vyun.html

2) **Из словаря забытых слов: выстилать** - плавно и быстро идти (о пароходе)Иван. Из-за острова вышел. Так и выстилает, так и выстилает.

А. Островский: Гаврило. Ты говоришь, выстилает? Иван. Выстилает. Страсть! Шибче «Самолета» бежит, так и меряет.

Comment: Vera, а не странно ли в свадебной песне упоминать рыбу- предвестника ненастья? Люди ведь очень суеверны.

Comment: Традиции русских свадеб были разные. Древнерусская народная свадьба включала много драматических моментов: подружки невесты пели грустные песни, невеста и ее мать плакали и причитали, девушки прощались с родным домом. На севере невеста должна была много плакать и причитать, иначе считалось, что она может обидеть свою семью. В западной части России свадьба была не такая грустная,а  вот на юге России свадьба была весельем.  http://nsportal.ru/shkola/muzyka/library/2013/07/04/traditsii-russkoy-svadebnoy-pesni

Comment: Грустные песни и плачь дело понятное. Но рыба-вьюн ведь редко (как у Вас написано) поднимается к поверхности воды, а  "быстрое плавание его на мелководье с поднятием придонного ила предшествует длительному ненастью". Зачем эту рыбу в свадебной песне вообще упоминать (тем более, что - предшествует ненастью)? Вроде как беду кликать. Да и не расстилается эта рыба НАД водой.

Comment: В песне, как я думаю, просто соотносится природное явление (стайка рыб, обычно живущих на дне, вдруг поднимается кверху и начинает быстро плавать, как бы выстилает поверхность воды, выражая ВОЛНЕНИЕ) и важный для каждой девушки шаг в новую жизнь, который  не может НЕ ВОЛНОВАТЬ ее, даже если это желанная свадьба  и надежда на будущее счастье.

Answer (score 0):

Вьюн - это пресноводная рыба. Мне удалось найти одну интересную  версию. [Интерпретация смыслового содержания народной песни
«Вьюн над водой»](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=823.LaMQZTlR4N0gC-xknr4b57z1kZ91N9ED4OK2Wu09ON7RCc1zfufDZ8z48GzIVpRSSYIXQ1LonGSCB91LpJQbkA.225a2be484d818ced392b44b4ceb10f11440a31b&url=http%3A%2F%2Fartmiro.ru%2Fblog%2Fvjun_nad_vodoj%2F2014-07-17-211&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9daDl0Ow0EQqBnwXqr2CGSTlhSDEzIy2U7BBTY65%2Fy93%2BqwDrx71SbSVJRsoLuhczA%3D%3D&data=&b64e=3&sign=ba5361060f5bce54e8665f8e2afdaa1e&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFFO69YeYKfJ67Gvax84D5dKtZ9EIUQdN6ianTiC-L_0UifdnhXINsP85eWtPKhRrR2xCM_h15qyJtzC5MnO0zYypfRveq-iq5QWWb1wchzjh-D_YPlwRXwmgPHRQhpk-dd2B38IZlgv34eZUozsimeeI24-l3xDabXtgKS1RoeFnum_a5_vIhfY&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCNQCW31z695H0nKLPu3GKO2z1WrMNadc8BZcFDHUQPxdtWoMNYusPGYZe6t7bNia7abifwLTAgJcbahMCjjscdICS_9gxV_YJ2Ad2axtJZ9mAJBH7n2mYOc2eaJotkTwVjyn5C85cnYFoJmivl2m96xxAU9aVGBQc95cM8QmRBWC4ImqEZboyvu1d1rjdYTI8VMGzv5DRiAtyOTVHdQRTYVJ4ZEPh-A3Am43tx7838ATohegeuhRBHYn17dxA74j4RuzbOMeMgL-jineEXV5C_I_t5HU_rKAR&l10n=ru&cts=1443270357369&mc=5.3542876208358505)